# Adding JButton by loop causes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, swing

I have a swing application which  I have declared a JButton array inside it's constructor inside that class I have created a for loop  in order to add a number of 114 JButton to  class container.

but when that class runs it gives the exception

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

On the statement that adding the Buttons to Container.

Can someone see the problem?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
   public Main()
   {
      Container pane = getContentPane();
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      JButton b[];
      int i;

      for (i = 0; i < 114; i++)
      {
         b = new JButton[i];
         panel.add(b[i]);
      }
      pane.add(panel);
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
   {
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Main m = new Main();
      m.setSize(500, 500);
      m.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't made expression like that

```
for(i=0; i<114;i++)
{
 b  = new JButton[i];
 panel.add(b[i]);
}
```

In first execution it is new JButton[0], so your array size is 0.

You should use Collection (fe. ArrayList) or fixed size JButton array.

```
JButton[] b  = new JButton[114];
for(i=0; i<114;i++)
{
 b[i]  = new JButton();
 panel.add(b[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At i = 0, `b = new JButton[i];` creates an array of size 0, so trying to reference `b[0]` (i.e. the first element) will be out of bounds.

And you never construct `b[i]`.

You probably want to move the array construction outside the loop, something like:

```
b = new JButton[114];
for (i = 0; i < 114; i++)
{
   b[i] = new JButton();
   panel.add(b[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since b is an array type which holding collection of JButton objects.So you need to create 
one JButton object for each location of that array. The code what Dukeling is given is 
correct approach. And also one thing you have forgotten,You need to define the size of
your array like `JButton b[]=new JButton[size];`